# Web pages ported to Android app using PhoneGap will not resize to display

Tags: javascript, android, resize, phonegap-build, html

I have a web-based tool that I have ported to Android using PhoneGap from my Github repository. When the app is installed and run on Android, though, the page is too big to fit on the display, and I have to keep moving it around within the display to make different parts of it visible and use the controls.

I have added a "meta" tag to the web page as some people have suggested, and I have specified a width and set it as user-scalable, but this doesn't work. I have also set "EnableViewportScale" to "true" in config.xml.

```
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=896, user-scalable=yes" />             
<title>Main Menu</title>
```

I've been at this for hours and nothing I've tried has worked. What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any assistance.

The config.xml I have looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id = "com.phonegap.dvams"
    version = "1.0.0">
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Description</description>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

Somebody with a similar problem reported that they changed something in an "AndroidManifest.xml" file. However I'm told PhoneGap generates this automatically when you compile, and only the config.xml file is available to me. Is there anything I can put in config.xml to make this work? If you have some javascript code to suggest as a solution, please could you tell me where it needs to go on the html pages.

I also tried the following code in my windows.onload event, but it just made all the text vanish from my page.

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

does this fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same result. The page is too big and I have to move it around to bring the rest of it on-screen.

I also tried 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />,

with the same result. I'm wondering if there's something else I need to do to make this work, like a reference in config.xml.

Comment: @Zenid I don't know how I can help you more BUT i can tell you that you can make changes to the android manifest without being afraid of losing them on every build. You can find the android manifest in the native folder of your android folder.

Answer (score 0):

Papakias - You were close. The string that finally worked was:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

I think "target-densitydpi=device-dpi" might have been the key here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to Know I helped! I Will edit my answer to contain the right code